# HTTP JSON Too Many Requests Steam Inventory

Tags: php, json, http, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to get user's steam inventory using this little piece of code:

```
    $url = $steamprofile['profileurl']."inventory/json/730/2";
    var_dump($url);
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));


    foreach($json->rgDescriptions as $value => $v) {
        if ($v->tradable === 1) {
            $name = $v->market_hash_name;
            $icon_url = $v->icon_url;
            ?>
            <div class="img__wrap">
                <img class="img__img" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/<?=$icon_url?>" />
                <div class="img__description_layer">
                     <p class="img__description"><?= $name ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    } else {

    }
}
```

But if i refresh the page about 2-4 times i get the HTTP 429 Too Many Requests error.
Is there any way to make this not happen, or is this just something in steam that i can't fix?

Comment: The problem is not with your code. A HTTP 429 means you are calling the API more often than allowed. It's a way for the server to throttle incoming requests to prevent DDOS attacks for example.

Comment: okay, does this also happen when someone has like, 2000+ items in their inventory? or just when i refresh the page 2-4 times

Comment: I would assume that it will be on page refresh only and it shouldn't matter how many items they hold in their inventory. Here is a bit more info on HTTP 429 - https://httpstatuses.com/429

Comment: okay then i'll just leave it like this, thanks!